# How to insert multiple rows?

Tags: php, arrays, activerecord, yii, transactions

I have a set of rows between 10 to 200, which i need to insert into Database. `Active Records` is slow for this task, i am using command builder by this way:

```
        $builder = Yii::app()->db->schema->commandBuilder;
        $command=$builder->createMultipleInsertCommand('AviaOrders',$ordersInfoToSave );
        $command=$builder->createMultipleInsertCommand('ItineraryInfo',$itineraryInfoToSave );
        $command->execute();
```

Where `$ordersInfoToSave` and `$itineraryInfoToSave` are arrays of attributes with following structure.

```
 array(array(name=>value,...),array(name=>value,...),...)
```

Since i am using Yii-1.1.3, i have not CommandBuilder's method `createMultipleInsertCommand`.

So, how to insert multiple rows, using `ActiveRecords` as well as  `CommandBuilder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a string of MySql Insert Command as

```
$ordersInfoToSave='';

foreach ($records as $record)
$ordersInfoSave.="('{$record['attribute1vlaue']}','{$record['attribute2vlaue']}'),";

if($ordersInfoSave !== NULL){
$ordersInfoSave=substr($ordersInfoSave,0,-1);
$query='Insert Into AviaOrders (`attribute1`,`attribute2`) values '.$ordersInfoSave;


Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();

}
```